# How to only extract text from elements that contains more than one word with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way for me to use `BeautifulSoup` to get the text of tags that contain more than one word?

For example if I had HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a>hello there</a>
        <a>hi</a>
    </div>
    <a>what's up</a>
    <a>stackoverflow</a>
</div>
```

...I just want to get:

```
hello there what's up
```

Comment: You can use xpath / rel. xpath to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use `BeautifulSoup` you could also use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) and iterate  its result, while checking if there is a whitespace:

```
' '.join(s for s in soup.stripped_strings if ' ' in s )
```

*Alternatively, you can check each tag individually with `.get_text()`, but I would recommend stripping the results `.get_text(strip=True)` before checking for a whitespace.*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div>
    <div>
        <a>hello there</a>
        <a>hi </a>
    </div>
    <a>what's up</a>
    <a>stackoverflow</a>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

' '.join(s for s in soup.stripped_strings if ' ' in s )
```

Comment: This works well!  Follow up question - what if I only want to filter out one-word text if that text is contained in a link (with an href property)?  For example '<a href="/foo"><span>hi</span></a><a>hello</a>' would give me just 'hello'?

Comment: Happy to help. To keep the post clean, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. Just drop the link to your new question here, so everybody could follow. Hint: Select Elements by its `tag` and `attribute` and use the alternative I came up to iterate and check the strings.